# I am trying to swap Eth to Dai using 0x-Api on on ropsten but my transaction reverted by EVM

Tags: 0x

Transaction hash: 0x9e4cd796a7f3a299ef412f8268e839e8a1600e01140bd2258d8a9d12ee5bf642

Transaction request we are sending to swap:
{
allowanceTarget: "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff"
buyAmount: "2159116314"
buyTokenAddress: "0x07865c6e87b9f70255377e024ace6630c1eaa37f"
buyTokenToEthRate: "2159.116314"
chainId: 3
data: "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"
estimatedGas: "0x1b198"
from: "0x36d5F7A5ec466cee88E87e1E1eea26b2468e4Ca1"
gas: "0x1b198"
gasLimit: "0x1b198"
gasPrice: "0x77359400"
guaranteedPrice: "2137.52515"
minimumProtocolFee: "0"
nonce: "0x13"
price: "2159.116314"
protocolFee: "0"
sellAmount: "1000000000000000000"
sellTokenAddress: "0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab"
sellTokenToEthRate: "1"
takerAddress: "0x36d5F7A5ec466cee88E87e1E1eea26b2468e4Ca1"
to: "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff"
value: "0x302e303031"
}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try supplying the `takerAddress` as we're able to perform an `eth_estimateGas` for you to get an accurate gas limit estimate. Without that we can only return what the source uses on average.

https://ropsten.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?takerAddress=0x36d5F7A5ec466cee88E87e1E1eea26b2468e4Ca1&sellToken=0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&buyToken=0x07865c6e87b9f70255377e024ace6630c1eaa37f&sellAmount=1000000000000000000.

Comment: bro, You just saved me! I was working for a couple of days. 
Thanks, A lot